# java how to combine two hashmap without duplicate entries

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I am trying to combine two different hashmaps. But in those two maps, there are some duplicate entries, so I have to remove thoese entries after combine.

For example:

HashMap 1:
100  hello
101  nice

HashMap 2:

100 hello
102 good

After combine, the hashmap should looks like:

100 hello
101 nice
102 good

I have tried `putall`,but seems it does not remove duplicate entries. 
Could someone help me on a fast way to do that?

Comment: Could you please post your code you use to do this?

Comment: Just to show that `putAll` is not the problem: http://ideone.com/CWMRDp

Comment: HashMap does not allow duplicates but it uses the equals method to determine this. It can only be concluded that your keys are not Integer but some other object where you haven't implemented equals correctly. You'll have to show us that for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem in your approach.

```
HashMap<String, Object> first = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> second = new HashMap<String, Object>();

first.put("100", "hello");
first.put("101", "nice");
second.put("100", "hello");
second.put("102", "good");

first.putAll(second);
System.out.println(first);
```

outputs

```
{102=good, 101=nice, 100=hello}
```

Try to check, if your handling of HashMaps is correct.

Comment: Right and it appears the class the OP is using for a key does not adhere to this. They need to post their code. See also ['Are "works for me" answers valid?'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: True, but it allows OP to re-check his approach. Please notice I didn't repost anyone's code.

Answer (score 1):

The keys of a `HashMap` can't be duplicates, because they are represented in a `Set`, so merging the two maps should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

**you can add two hashmap map1 and map2 to third hashmap map3 just declare the input type for value as Object as all the data type have their super class as Object class.**

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

HashMap<String, Object> map3;
map3 = new HashMap<>();

map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```